# Yelp DataSet - Access specifically to review.jason

Tags: python, json, yelp

Im doing an online course where we use the Yelp Dataset.

The dataset is available here
https://www.yelp.com/dataset

The download arrives as a yelp.dataset.tar file.

If I extract that file using say a win 7, it becomes a file named "yelp_dataset"  of type - I'm not sure because it doesnt have a "."  extenstion.
The course which uses python to get into the "Review Data" goes straight to

```
path = 'C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/Python Folder/Data/yelp_dataset/review.json'
f = open(path)
d = jsonloads(f.readline))
```

however I obviously don't have review.json or any of the other .json files like user.json etc.
Having read the documentation on the dataset I read that "Each file is composed of a single object type, one JSON-object per-line." however not sure how to get at the review.json object.

Many thanks

Comment: How did you uncompress it? Often `tar` is used with `gzip` and after untaring it may need now to uncompress `gzip`. Where did you get this dataset? if you would add link (in question, not in comments) then we could also download it and see this file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Furas  - you put me on the right track.
I should not have been extracting the file using Winzip or similar.
The correct thing to do is to use Python to extract the files.

```
path = 'aFILEPATH/yelp_dataset/yelp_dataset.tar'

# open file
file = tarfile.open(path)

# extracting file
file.extractall()

file.close()
```